# The include file 'FILENAME' was not found

Tags: asp-classic, include, virtual

I've searched and I have seen a lot of advise regarding ParentPaths, etc, but this is on shared hosting and I am not sure I can set this.
Basically, we're moving a website from a VPS to shared hosting. The code works on the VPS, but on shared hosting, it's erroring with:

```
The include file 'FILENAME' was not found.
```

The code is:

```vb
<!--#include virtual="FILENAME" -->
```

I've tried altering the path to relative and absolute, but the error persists.
Thanks.

Comment: can you take a screenshot of how your site is set on hosting IIS(folders structure) and what is location of this FILENAME. Right now you are asking to point us to Earth center from the Pegasus galaxy...

Comment: I managed to sort this, but cannot close it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user2069576 Leave your answer then after a few hours you can come back and accept it. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).